# Creating fancy section pages for Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, sectioning

I am currently struggling to create fancy-looking section pages in `Beamer` to achieve the following layout:

[image: section]

Based on my question on the matching TOC ([fancy-table-of-contents-for-beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106007/how-to-create-a-fancy-table-of-contents-for-beamer)) I came up with the following code which does not look so bad but does to really resemble the given layout. Any idea how to improve the code?

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{section shading}{2cm}{
color(0cm)=(LightSlateGrey!15);
color(3cm)=(LightSlateGrey)
}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{subsection shading}{2cm}{
color(0cm)=(red!15);
color(1cm)=(red);
color(3cm)=(green)
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{section number/.style={
    draw=none,
    rectangle,    
    left color=gray!40,
    right color=gray!20!black,
    minimum size=3.5em,
    text=white,
  },
  section/.style={
    draw=none,
    rectangle,    
    shading=section shading,
    minimum height=3.5em,
    minimum width=0.9\textwidth,
    text width=0.9\textwidth,
    text=black,
    align=left
  },
  subsection/.style={
    draw=none,
    rectangle,    
    shading=subsection shading,
    minimum height=2em,
    minimum width=0.9\textwidth,
    text width=0.9\textwidth,
    text=black,
    align=left
  }
}

\begin{document}

\frame{

\begin{tabular}{p{1.2cm}p{9cm}} 
\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\node[section number]{\bfseries\Large 123}; & \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\node[section]{\bfseries\large fxdfsdf}; \\ & \\
& \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\node[subsection]{\bfseries fxdfsdf};
\end{tabular}

}

\end{document}
```

[image: mycode]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one possibility; the section frames are automatically created using `\AtBeginSection`. I used your colors and shadings, but you can change them easily (and, of course, feel free to make any other changes, according to your needs):

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,shadings}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{section shading}{2cm}{
color(0cm)=(LightSlateGrey!15);
color(3cm)=(LightSlateGrey)
}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{subsection shading}{2cm}{
color(0cm)=(red!15);
color(1cm)=(red);
color(3cm)=(green)
}

\tikzset{section number/.style={
    inner sep=0pt,
    draw=none,
    rectangle,    
    left color=gray!40,
    right color=gray!20!black,
    minimum size=3.5em,
    text=white,
    text width=3.5em,
   align=center
  },
  section/.style={
    inner sep=0pt,
    draw=none,
    rectangle,    
    shading=section shading,
    minimum height=3.5em,
    minimum width=0.9\textwidth,
    text width=\the\dimexpr\paperwidth-3.8em\relax,
    text=black,
    align=left
  },
  subsection/.style={
    inner sep=0pt,
    draw=none,
    rectangle,    
    shading=subsection shading,
    minimum height=2em,
    minimum width=0.9\textwidth,
    text width=\the\dimexpr\paperwidth-3.8em\relax,
    text=black,
    align=left
  }
}

\makeatletter
\def\sectionsubtitle#1{\gdef\@sectionsubtitle{#1}}
\AtBeginSection[]{%
\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[gray!10] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
\fill[left color=red!40,right color=green!15] 
  ( $ (current page.north west) + (0pt,-80pt) $ ) -- 
  ( $ (current page.north west) + (80pt,0pt) $ ) --
  ( $ (current page.north west) + (300pt,0pt) $ ) --
  ( $ (current page.north west) + (0pt,-300pt) $ ) -- 
  cycle;
\fill[left color=LightSlateGrey!40,right color=LightSlateGrey!05] 
  ( $ (current page.north west) + (300pt,0pt) $ ) -- 
  ( $ (current page.north west) + (500pt,0pt) $ ) --
  ( $ (current page.north west) + (0pt,-500pt) $ ) --
  ( $ (current page.north west) + (0pt,-300pt) $ ) -- 
  cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[section number,anchor=west] at (current page.west) {\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont\two@digits\thesection}; 
\node[section,anchor=east] at (current page.east) (title) 
  {\hfill\parbox[c][3.5em][c]{\the\dimexpr\paperwidth-4.2em\relax}{\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont\insertsectionhead}\hfill}; 
\node[subsection,below= 2pt of title]  (subtitle) 
  {\hfill\parbox[c][2em][c]{\the\dimexpr\paperwidth-4.2em\relax}{\@sectionsubtitle}\hfill}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\gdef\@sectionsubtitle{}
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\sectionsubtitle{Test Subtitle One}
\section{Test Section One}
\begin{frame}
Test Frame
\end{frame}

\sectionsubtitle{Test Subtitle Two}
\section{Test Section Two}
\begin{frame}
Test Frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

All you have to do is to use `\sectionsubtitle` before each `\section` command.