# Custom TOC in beamer - customizing the TOC layout

Tags: beamer, sectioning, table-of-contents

At the moment I'm developing a corporate identity for the `beamer` class of my institute.
In fact a power point solution is available and I'm trying to rebuild a tex-friendly version.

However, at the moment I'm trying to build a custom TOC, which is repeated with each new section (this I already accomplished), with special format: I want the sections to be in rounded `beamercolorbox`es, but the whole TOC should be displayed (in the manner of `\tableofcontents[currentsection]`).

[image: Screenshot of my 'TOC']

My current code is in the MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{test}{fg = white, bg = red}
    \AtBeginSection[]{
        \begin{frame}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded = true]{test}
        \thesection.\ \insertsection \\
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \end{frame}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\section{This is the first section}
\begin{block}{This is the first block}
    Blocktext
\end{block}

\section{This is the second section, but I also want the the first one displayed with its box!}
\begin{frame}{frame}
    Frametext 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

*Afaik* there is no way to get the round boxes around the sections in the normal TOC or am I missing something? That's why I'm trying to make my own TOC.

Hopefully I could explain myself well enough...

Best regards

Patrick

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I tried to :-) I added a MWE and shortened my question!

Comment: There's a way to get round boxed in the table of contents: [How to create a fancy table of contents for Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106007/13304) shows you how to achieve that.