# How can I store an icon and a color with the section and use it in the \tableofcontents of beamer?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

My goal is to create a fancier agenda page and for this I would like to define e.g. an icon and a color for the section that shall be used to format the table of contents. Maybe finally the ToC is actually formatted through TikZ and not as a simple list, hence I am interested in general how to store more information than just the section name in the *.toc file and re-use it with the `\tableofcontents`-command or maybe define my own `\fancytoc`-command.

Here is an MWE that defines a `\sectionsymbol` and a `sectioncolor`, as well as a command to set them along with the section title `\myfancysection`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\definecolor{sectioncolor}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\newcommand{\sectionsymbol}{\relax}
\newcommand{\sectionstart}{\frame{\textcolor{sectioncolor}{\sectionsymbol\ \secname}}}

\newcommand{\myfancysection}[3]{\colorlet{sectioncolor}{#1}\renewcommand{\sectionsymbol}{#2}\section{#3}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Agenda}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\myfancysection{red}{\faAmbulance}{My red section}
\sectionstart

\myfancysection{green}{\faAutomobile}{My green section}
\sectionstart


\begin{frame}{Agenda as I wanted to be automatically}
\begin{description}[\faAutomobile]
    \item[\color{red}\faAmbulance] \textcolor{red}{My red section}
    \item[\color{green}\faAutomobile] \textcolor{green}{My green section}
\end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The last frame is just an illustration of how one could use the additional information to format the ToC, as mentioned I could also imagine to build the ToC through TikZ and I don't necessarily want to have a solution that only stores a color and a symbol, but maybe a list of key-value pairs, if that is not too advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigation, I found a neat way, combining [write contents of an environment to document and toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60738/write-contents-of-an-environment-to-document-and-toc) and [How to add additional information to chapters and their entry in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138810/how-to-add-additional-information-to-chapters-and-their-entry-in-the-table-of-co) and [How to create a fancy table of contents for Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106007/how-to-create-a-fancy-table-of-contents-for-beamer)

The basic idea is to write some commands into the `*.toc`-file and then reference them in the `section in toc` template. Putting everything together we get:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\definecolor{sectioncolor}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\newcommand{\sectionsymbol}{\relax}
\newcommand{\sectionstart}{\frame{\textcolor{sectioncolor}{\sectionsymbol\ \secname}}}

\newcommand{\myfancysection}[3]{\addtocontents{toc}{%
\protect\colorlet{sectioncolor}{#1}}\colorlet{sectioncolor}{#1}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\sectionsymbol}{\protect#2}}\renewcommand{\sectionsymbol}{#2}\section{#3}}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\textcolor{sectioncolor}{\sectionsymbol\ \inserttocsection}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Agenda}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\myfancysection{red}{\faAmbulance}{My red section}
\sectionstart

\myfancysection{green}{\faAutomobile}{My green section}
\sectionstart

\end{document}
```

And on the agenda page:

[image]